# A point concerning Suciu's paper.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, invariant-subspace

I have a question concerning a point given in the paper written by Suciu entitled  **on the semi group of isometries** (published in Studia Math. 1968).

In Theorem 2 of this paper, it is  claimed that $N$ is a wandering subspace  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gRgF.png). I do not get this point.

Comment: Down vote! I will extremely  be happy to know why! At least  give me a negative comment. Did you really get what the question is?

Comment: Maybe you have already answered this, but what is a wandering space? In other words what point in the image specifically don't you get? Also wrt the image, $S$ is a subset of a group without inverses? Or how does $S^{-1}$ make sense?